# Counting and removing duplicates in an array c

Tags: c, arrays, duplicates

Let's say I have an array with [2,4,6,7, 7, 4,4]
I want a program that can iterate through, and then print out something like this:

```
Value:     Count:
2          1
4          3
6          1
7          2
```

I don't want it to print out ex 4 three times.
What I got so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfInts; i++)
{
    dub[i] = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < numberOfInts; y++)
    {
        if (enarray[i] == enarray[y])
        {

            dub[i]++;
        }
    }

}
```

So basically I check each element in the array against all the elements, and for every duplicate I add one to the index in the new array dub[]. 
So if I ran this code with the example array above, and then printed it out with  I'd get something like this:
1,3,1,2,2,3,3. These are pretty confusing numbers, because I don't really know which numbers these belong to. Especially when I'll randomize the numbers in the array. And then I have to remove numbers so I only have one of each. Anyone got a better solution?

Comment: Your char array, does it contain only characters from '0' to '9'?

Comment: I'm actually using ints, updated it now.

Comment: suggest keep an array (int numbers[10] = {0}) then for each value read in the source array numbers[[sourceValue]++;  Then when printing the results, for( int x=0;x<10; x++) printf("number: %d occurs %d times\n", x, numbers[x] );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through the array while checking for each element if it has been repeated in which case you increment it's count (the loop checks only values a head saving processing time). This let you accomplish what you needed without creating any extra buffer array or structure.

The bool 'bl' prevents repeated printing

```
int main() {

    int arr[] = { 2, 4, 6, 7, 7, 4, 4 };
    int size = (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int));

    printf("Value:\tCount\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int count = 0, bl = 1; //or 'true' for print
        //check elements ahead and increment count if repeated value is found 
        for (int j = i; j < size; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        //check if it has been printed already
        for (int j = i-1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                bl = 0; //print 'false'
            }
        }
        if (bl) { printf("%d\t\t%d\n", arr[i], count); } 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The indentation is broken and the code doesn't work.

Comment: I'm struggling to get the indentation right since I'm on my phone but the code does work

Comment: Let me know if you fix it.

Comment: Just did ;)
sorry for the non-sense code. I finally got to open my laptop and checked it

Comment: Oh yeah, its because index j never gets to be zero. I've fixed it

Comment: @this I fixed it. Thanks for your comments :)

Answer (score 1):

Given the char array only contains '0' to '9', you may utilize a trivial lookup table like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    char c;
    int  num;
} TSet;

TSet my_set[] =
{
    { '0', 0 },
    { '1', 0 },
    { '2', 0 },
    { '3', 0 },
    { '4', 0 },
    { '5', 0 },
    { '6', 0 },
    { '7', 0 },
    { '8', 0 },
    { '9', 0 },
};

int main()
{
    char a[] = {'2','4','6','7','7', '4','4'};
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(char); i++ )
    {
        my_set[ a[i] - '0' ].num++;
    }

    printf( "%-10s%-10s\n", "Value:", "Count:" );
    for( i = 0; i < sizeof(my_set) / sizeof(TSet); i++ )
    {
        if( my_set[i].num != 0 )
        {
            printf( "%-10c%-10d\n", my_set[i].c, my_set[i].num );
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Value:    Count:    
2         1         
4         3         
6         1         
7         2
```

Comment: Actually I didn't use chars, I used ints. Sorry about that. Still the same method to solve it?

Comment: should be, just replace the type

Comment: let me know if you can modify it work with int. I have it work already.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the complexity here. I think there are two approaches that are performant and easy to implement:

Counting Sort

- requires int array of size of the biggest element in your array
- overall complexity O(n + m) where m is the biggest element in your array

qsort and enumeration

- qsort works in O(n * log(n)) and gives you a sorted array
- once the array is sorted, you can simply iterate over it and count
- overall complexity O(n*log(n))

Answer (score 1):

1. sort the array, typically by using the [`qsort()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html) function
2. iterate over all elements counting successively equal elements and if the next different element is detected print the count of the former

This works on *any* number of different elements. Also no second array is needed.

Comment: How can I sort an array in C?

Answer (score 0):

Put a print statement in the outer *for loop* to print *value* and *repetition*

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfInts; i++)
{
    dub[i] = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < numberOfInts; y++)
    {
        if (enarray[i] == enarray[y])
        {

            dub[i]++;
        }
    }
printf("%d%d",enarray[i], dub[i]);
}
```

Comment: That wasn't exactly what I was asking for.

Comment: @Jullix993 but in your question you asked for a solution so that you could know to which number does those repetitions belong. This is the answer for that.

Comment: Sure, I see how you thought that. Well what I want is the output with value and count. Thx anyway

Comment: @Jullix993 buddy this will print value viz enarray[] and count viz dub[]

Comment: Yeah I know how it will print it, but look one more time on my question where I wrote value and count output, it will not be the same.

Comment: The values in the output will be like value    Count<br>a[0]   4<br>a[1]   1<br>a[2]   3<br>and so on

Answer (score 0):

You have the general idea.  In addition to your input array, I would suggest three more arrays:

- a `used` array that keeps track of which entries in the input have already been counted.
- a `value` array that keeps track of the distinct numbers in the `input` array.
- a `count` array that keeps track of how many times a number appears.

For example, after processing the 2 and the 4 in the input array, the array contents would be

```
input[] = { 2,4,6,7,7,4,4 };
used[]  = { 1,1,0,0,0,1,1 };  // all of the 2's and 4's have been used
value[] = { 2,4           };  // unique numbers found so far are 2 and 4
count[] = { 1,3           };  // one '2' and three '4's
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is strange. Normally, I'd create a struct with 2 members, like 'number' and 'count'. But let's try exactly what you're asking for (unidimensional array with each number followed by it's count):

```
int 
   i,
   numberOfInts = 7,
   numberOfDubs = 0,
   enarray[7] = {2,4,6,7,7,4,4},
   dub[14]; // sizeof(enrray) * 2 => maximum number of dubs (if there are no duplicates)

// For every number on enarray
for(i = 0; i < numberOfInts; i++)
{
    int jump = 0;

    // Check if we have already counted it
    // Only check against pairs: Odds are the dub counter
    for(int d = 0; d < numberOfDubs && !jump; d += 2)
    {
       if(dub[d] == enarray[i])
       {
          jump = 1;
       }
    }

    // If not found, count it
    if(!jump)
    {
       // Assign the new number
       dub[numberOfDubs] = enarray[i];
       dub[numberOfDubs + 1] = 1;

       // We can begin from 'i + 1'
       for(int y = i + 1; y < numberOfInts; y++)
       {
          if(enarray[i] == enarray[y])
          {
               dub[numberOfDubs + 1]++;
          }
       }

       // Increment dub's counter by 2: number and it's counter
       numberOfDubs += 2;
    }
}

// Show results
for(i = 0; i < numberOfDubs; i += 2)
{
   printf("%d repeated %d time%s\n", dub[i], dub[i + 1], (dub[i + 1] == 1 ? "" : "s"));
}
```

Comment: What's strange about my question? If using struct is the way to go, then sure I could do it.

Comment: There is not an unique answer. It's me who'd do it with an struct, which will let the code very clean and structured ;) Would you like another answer with struct?

Comment: It's strange because you asked for an unidimensional array containing the numbers and just after each, it's counter. I'd better not merge things: it's unclear. But you might need this for some unknown reason...

Comment: Oh I see, my bad. The order of the number isn't relevant, I just wrote them that for some reason.